# How to calculate the cumulative balance per customer account with a JTable?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable in which I have the operations of several customer accounts.

I want to calculate the cumulative balance with each operation and this for each account. In my JTable I have a column (of type string) in which there is a list of accounts, another column (of type int) in which there is the amount of operations.

How will I be able to retrieve the list of accounts and calculate the cumulative balance of transactions for each account?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ! Don't forget to give us more details (and code examples), so we can answer your question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can better understand what you really need. Please don't post your entire code, but rather create a small class which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I slightly reworded your question to make it better to read, and added the missing java tag. But I agree to the comments: you should A) first try to write some code of your own to then B) ask about problems with that. Most questions that only present requirements (but no effort to solve the problem) are resulting in rather negative feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution of my problems

```
int nombreDeLignes = model.getRowCount(); 
    double cumul=0; 
    String numcompte=null; // une valeur qui n'existe nulle part
    for(int i=0; i<nombreDeLignes; i++) {

        String numcompteLigne = model.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
        if ( numcompte==null || !numcompte.equals(numcompteLigne) ) {

             numcompte = numcompteLigne;
             cumul=0;
        }

        cumul+= (int) model.getValueAt(i, 5);           
        model.setValueAt(cumul, i, 9);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to create Consolidate the Data and create SubTotal

```
    public enum AggregatorType {
        SUM, AVG, DISPLAY, LABEL
    }

    public class DataRow {
        private final Object[] values;
        private final boolean totalRow;

        public DataRow(Object[] values, boolean totalRow) {
            this.values = values;
            this.totalRow = totalRow;
        }

        public Object[] getValues() {
            return values;
        }

        public boolean isTotalRow() {
            return totalRow;
        }

        public static Object[] getvalues(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof DataRow) {
                return ( (DataRow) obj).getValues() ;
            } else if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
                return (Object[]) obj;
            } else {
                return new Object[] { obj};
            }
        }
    }

    public class Aggregator {

        private final int column;
        private final String prefix;
        private final String subfix;
        private final AggregatorType type;

        public Aggregator( int column,AggregatorType type)
        {
            this(column,type,null);
        }

        public Aggregator( int column,AggregatorType type,String prefix)
        {
            this(column,type,prefix,null);
        }

        public Aggregator( int column,AggregatorType type,String prefix,String subfix)
        {
            this.column=column;
            this.type=type;
            this.prefix=prefix;
            this.subfix=subfix;
        }


        public int getColumn() {
            return column;
        }

        public AggregatorType getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public Object aggregate( List<?> objects) {

            Object object = null;
            switch(this.type) {
                case SUM : object = total(objects); break;
                case AVG : object = avg(objects);    break;     
                case LABEL:  object = ""; break;        
                default:  object = display(objects); break; 
            }
            if( object != null && ( prefix != null || subfix != null )) {
                return ( prefix == null ? "" : prefix.toString() ) +
                        object.toString() + 
                        ( subfix == null ? "" : subfix.toString() );
            } else {
                return object;
            }
        }

        public Object display( List<?> objects) {       
            return DataRow.getvalues(objects.get(0))[column];
        }

        public Object total( List<?> objects) {
            double total = 0.0;
            for( Object object : objects ) {
                Object[] objA = DataRow.getvalues(object);
                Object value = objA[column];
                if( value instanceof Number ) {
                    total += ( ( Number ) value  ).doubleValue();   
                }       
            }
            return total;
        }

        public Object avg( List<?> objects) {
            double total = 0.0;
            int count = 0;
            for( Object object : objects ) {
                Object[] objA = DataRow.getvalues(object);
                Object value = objA[column];
                if( value instanceof Number ) {
                    total += ( ( Number ) value  ).doubleValue();   
                    count++;
                }       
            }
            return count > 0 ? ( total / count ) : 0.0;
        }
    }

    import java.util.List;

    public class SubTotalCreator {
        private final int columnIndex;
        private final boolean grandTotal;
        private final List<Aggregator> aggregatorList;

        public SubTotalCreator(int index, List<Aggregator> aggregatorList) {
            this(index, false, aggregatorList);
        }

        public SubTotalCreator(int index, boolean grandTotal, List<Aggregator> aggregatorList) {
            this.aggregatorList = aggregatorList;
            this.columnIndex = index;
            this.grandTotal = grandTotal;
        }

        public boolean canCreateSubTotal(Object[] object1, Object[] object2) {
            return !object1[columnIndex].equals(object2[columnIndex]);
        }

        public Object[] createSubTotal(List<?> subList) {
            Object[] obj = DataRow.getvalues(subList.get(0));
            int length = obj.length;
            Object[] subtotal = new Object[length];
            for (Aggregator aggregator : aggregatorList) {
                Object value = aggregator.aggregate(subList);
                subtotal[aggregator.getColumn()] = value;
            }
            return subtotal;
        }

        public int getColumnIndex() {
            return columnIndex;
        }

        public boolean isGrandTotal() {
            return grandTotal;
        }

        public List<Aggregator> getAggregatorList() {
            return aggregatorList;
        }

    }

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Consolidator {
        private final List<SubTotalCreator> list;
        private final Comparator<Object[]> comparator;
        private List<Object[]> objects;
        private List<DataRow> rows;

        public Consolidator(Comparator<Object[]> comparator, List<SubTotalCreator> list) {
            this.comparator = comparator;
            this.list = list;
        }

        public List<Object[]> getSummary() {
            List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int index = 0; index < rows.size(); index++) {
                DataRow row = rows.get(index);
                if (row.isTotalRow()) {
                    list.add(row.getValues());
                }
            }
            return list;
        }


public Object[][] getAllRowAsArray() {
    Object[][] list =new Object[rows.size()][];
    for (int index = 0; index < rows.size(); index++) {
        DataRow row = rows.get(index);
        list[index]=row.getValues();
    }
    return list;
}
        public List<Object[]> getAllRows() {
            List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int index = 0; index < rows.size(); index++) {
                DataRow row = rows.get(index);
                list.add(row.getValues());
            }
            return list;
        }

        public List<Object[]> getObjects() {
            return objects;
        }

        public List<DataRow> getRows() {
            return rows;
        }

        public void setObjects(Object[][] objects) {
            List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int index = 0; index < objects.length; index++) {
                list.add(objects[index]);
            }
            setObjects(list);
        }

        public void setObjects(List<Object[]> objects) {
            this.objects = objects;
        }

        private void createDataRow() {
            List<DataRow> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int index = 0; index < objects.size(); index++) {
                list.add(new DataRow(objects.get(index), false));
            }
            this.rows = list;
        }

        public void consolidate() {
            objects.sort(comparator);
            createDataRow();
            computeSubTotal();
            computeGrandTotal();
        }

        public void computeSubTotal() {
            for (SubTotalCreator creator : list) {
                if (!creator.isGrandTotal()) {
                    computeSubTotal(creator);
                }
            }
        }

        public void computeGrandTotal() {
            for (SubTotalCreator creator : list) {
                if (creator.isGrandTotal()) {
                    computeSubTotal(creator);
                }
            }
        }

        public void computeSubTotal(SubTotalCreator creator) {

            List<?> list = null;
            if (!creator.isGrandTotal()) {
                ArrayList<DataRow> subList = new ArrayList<DataRow>();
                DataRow prevDataRow = null;
                for (int index = 0; index < rows.size(); index++) {
                    DataRow dataRow = rows.get(index);
                    if (dataRow.isTotalRow())
                        continue;

                    if (prevDataRow != null) {
                        boolean flag = creator.canCreateSubTotal(prevDataRow.getValues(), dataRow.getValues());
                        if (flag) {
                            DataRow subTotal = new DataRow(creator.createSubTotal(subList), true);
                            rows.add(index, subTotal);
                            subList.clear();
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                    subList.add(dataRow);
                    prevDataRow = dataRow;
                }
                list = subList;
            } else {
                list = objects;
            }

            DataRow subTotal = new DataRow(creator.createSubTotal(list), true);
            rows.add(subTotal);
        }

        public static void print(Object[][] objects) {
            for (Object[] objA : objects) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.asList(objA));
            }
        }

        public static void print(List<Object[]> objects) {
            for (Object[] objA : objects) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.asList(objA));
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] str) {

            Object[][] accountDetails = new Object[][] { { "Abhi", 20 }, { "Abhi", 200 }, { "Sekar", 100 }, { "Abhi", 45 },
                    { "Sekar", 120 }, { "Abhi", 35 }, { "Abhi", 40 }, { "Sekar", 500 } };

            Comparator<Object[]> comparator = new Comparator<Object[]>() {
                public int compare(Object[] obj1, Object[] obj2) {
                    return ((String) obj1[0]).compareTo((String) obj2[0]);
                }
            };

            List<SubTotalCreator> list = new ArrayList<SubTotalCreator>();

            List<Aggregator> aggregatorList = new ArrayList<Aggregator>();
            aggregatorList.add(new Aggregator(0, AggregatorType.DISPLAY, null, " 's Total"));
            aggregatorList.add(new Aggregator(1, AggregatorType.SUM));
            SubTotalCreator creator = new SubTotalCreator(0, aggregatorList);

            list.add(creator);

            List<Aggregator> grandAggList = new ArrayList<Aggregator>();
            grandAggList.add(new Aggregator(0, AggregatorType.LABEL, "Grand Total"));
            grandAggList.add(new Aggregator(1, AggregatorType.SUM));
            SubTotalCreator creator2 = new SubTotalCreator(0, true, grandAggList);

            list.add(creator2);

            Consolidator consolidator = new Consolidator(comparator, list);
            consolidator.setObjects(accountDetails);
            System.out.println("Before Consolidate ");
            print(consolidator.getObjects());
            consolidator.consolidate();
            System.out.println("After Consolidate ");
            print(consolidator.getAllRows());

            System.out.println("After Consolidate Summary Alone ");
            print(consolidator.getSummary());


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    JTable table = new JTable( consolidator.getAllRowAsArray(),new String[] {"Name" ,"Amount"});
    frame.getContentPane().add( new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize( 400,400);
    frame.setVisible( true);
        }

    }
```